# PCA in R: How to output the data outside of the confidence eclipse from PCA?

Tags: r, pca

I have added a confidence eclipse in a PCA plot using ggfortify package. My question is how to output the data which is outside of the confidence eclipse or how did I know which data is outside of the confidence eclipse. Thank you! Here is my code:

```
library(ggfortify)    
input<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000, mean = 10, sd = 2),nrow=100))
ann<-c(rep("center1", 40), rep("center2",60))
input2<-cbind.data.frame(input,ann)
pca_res <- prcomp(input, scale. = FALSE)
autoplot(pca_res, data=input2,x=1,y=2,colour='ann', shape=FALSE, label=TRUE, label.size=2.5, frame=TRUE, frame.type='norm')
```

Comment: Can you only plot the ellipse and add the points later with *points*?

Comment: Hi @cdalitz Could you please show me how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test this because your code relies on *ggplot*, which fails to install for my R version with an error message "not available for your R version".